# switching from a CustomAdapter ListView to an standard ArrayAdapter ListView fails

Tags: android, android-layout

I recently got interested in Android coding and working my way through several tutorials. however, right now i m stuck for a day and hope you guys can help me out.

basically i want to create a main menu and a submenu for every main menue entry. (right now this is only the case for the first entry)

For the main menu I used a ListView with different icons (realized with a custom adapter). Selecting one of the menu entries works fine in general, but if I choose to configure the onitemclick to start a new activity which is another (simple) ListView which uses the ArrayAdapter it breaks after switching into the submenu activity.

Strangely if i use the ArrayAdapter in both ListViews it is no problem; also when using CustomAdapter in both.

Here is the code, thanks in advance for any help ;)

main menu:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into Array contentmenu
    String[] contentmenu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mainmenu_cats);
    // storing icons in Array
    TypedArray iconarray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mainmenu_icons);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ImageAndTextAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, contentmenu, iconarray));

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {


          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          switch( position )
            {
               case 0:  Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SubActivity.class);     
                        startActivity(newActivity0);
                        break;

               case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SubActivity2.class);     
                        startActivity(newActivity1);                            
                        break;

            }

      }
    });


}
```

submenu:

```
public class SubActivity extends ListActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] submen_1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.submenu_1);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, R.layout.list_item1, R.id.submen1, submen_1));

    ListView sublv1 = getListView();

    // listening to single list item on click
    sublv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Page1.class);     
          // sending data to new activity
          newActivity.putExtra("position",position);
          startActivity(newActivity);

          }
    });
    }
```

xml main menu:
list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/option_icon"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/option_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16dp" >
</TextView>
```

sub menu:
list_item1.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon1"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:src="@drawable/ic_action_google_play" />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/submen1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16dp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: what problem u are getting with current code and also add logcat  results with question if application is crashing

Comment: it always crashes when selecting the first item of the main menu list. here is the [logcat](https://mega.co.nz/#!PctWhLiS)

key QUs2IE9wEh7vAqCROGvQuUnUahQQSWCpoypPEhOKfc0

Comment: plz use http://pastebin.com/ for sharing logcat

Comment: plz also post mainmenu_icons,.mainmenu_cats and list_item layout xml using http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @ Joy : actually you are missing to add `android:layout_width` in xml layouts somewhere plz recheck it

Comment: ok, thanks for the comments so far. i renamed the files correctly. here is the [link to the icons and cats](http://pastebin.com/kBfZfHa0)

Comment: ok you are right. the xml files missed the width attributes for the actual linar layout in list_item1.xml. now it works, thanks so much ;)

Comment: most welcome friend. see my answer if it help then mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are not defining Hight and Width for `LinearLayout` in both `list_item.xml` and `list_item1.xml` layouts . add height-width as :

**In list_item.xml :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <!-- PUT YOUR ImageView or other xml elements here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

and do same for `list_item1.xml` layout